# Only a type can be imported

Tags: java, class, jsp

There are quite a few threads about this, however I have been unsuccessful and making this work. I am trying to call a class from jsp page.

```
package org.confucius;  

public class HelloWorld {  
    public static String getGreeting ()  
    {  
      return "Hello World!";  
    }  
}
```

HelloWorld.jsp

```
<html>  
  <head>  
       <%@ page import="org.confucius.HelloWorld" %>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <p><%= HelloWorld.getGreeting() %></p>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

The following error is returned. Can someone please tell me all the configuration necessary to make this work? The compiled class resides in the CLASSPATH.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.confucius.HelloWorld resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /HelloWorld.jsp
HelloWorld cannot be resolved

Stacktrace:

org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems things are setup correctly. The class is in the correct directory and the structure seems to be good. Since reading these messages, I put all my stuff into an IDE. (Eclipse) to see if that would help and it returns the same thing. "HelloWorld cannot be resolved" Calling it a night gents. Thanks again for your help. I am pretty new to java if you couldn't tell...so I probably have something stupid going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing before the `<html>` block. I think imports should be done first in the document.
If that doesn't work, check your project directory. Make sure that they are in the right folder. For **example**, your HelloWorld class should be in:

```
C:/Tomcat/webapps/yourApp/WEB-INF/classes/org/confucius
```

Answer (score -1):

I looked again, your code is right.

maybe you should clean the servlet server like `Tomcat`, delete the work path(in `Tomcat` is `tomcat/work`),  redeploy you project and restart the server again.

Comment: Ok...Its fixed in Eclipse. I set the Native Library Path and the error went away. Tomorrow I will try redeploy and see how it goes. Thanks again.